# Calculating Cumulative values using MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table:

```
Month_Year              MV                    MI
----------------------------------------------------------
August 2016              3                    100
October 2016             2                    150
September 2016           1                    100
January 2017             4                    200
```

I need to create the next output table

```
Month_Year               MV       AMV          MI     AMI
----------------------------------------------------------
January 2016             0        0            0      0
...
July 2016                0        0            0      0 
August 2016              3        3           100    100
September 2016           1        4           100    200
October 2016             2        6           150    350
November 2016            0        6           0      350
December 2016            0        6           0      350
January 2017             4        10          200    550
```

At month M, for column AMV, AMV is the ccumulative value of all the AV ones before that month and month M. For example, AMV is 4 on 'September 2016' because in 'August 16' AV is 3 and 1 for 'September 2016'. Similarly for AMI. How can this be done?. Notice that the Month_Year column is not necessarily ordered. Thanks

ADDITIONAL INFO
After using the DATE_FORMAT(original_Date, '%Y %m') I was able to convert the first table to:

```
Month_Year              MV                    MI
----------------------------------------------------------
2016 08                  3                    100
2016 10                  2                    150
2016 09                  1                    100
2017 01                  4                    200
```

Could this simplify the problem? Why not to use DATE_FORMAT(original_Date, '%m %Y')?

Comment: The fact that the Month_Year is useless for ordering I assume is your fault. The table should have a year column and a month column, both containing numbers. If you want the result query to translate the month to words then use a join to a table via foreign keys. Once you have a vaguely sensible schema, the rest is easy.

Comment: Well, the customer needed that "month_year" format, so I tried to provide it. I used the command: DATE_FORMAT(OrigDate, '%M %Y') to get the month year string. I was also thinking on using other other table with month_year ordered as it should be

Comment: I just changed the command to obtain the month year DATE_FORMAT(origDate, '%m %Y')  so now I have the strings  "08 2016", "09 2016", "10 2016". Could this problem be solved now?

Comment: This simplifies the problem, however I have already given you an answer to the original, more complex, formulation. Did you check it out?

Comment: It is showing January 2016 with non Zero values... Anyway.. your algorithm looks very interesting. thanks

Comment: The output that the customer re4quires has no immediate bearing on the schema used to store the data. I have already told you that the data must be stored as year and month in two separate numeric columns. That is basic 1st Normal Form. You worry about the display once you have done the donkey work with the stored data.

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga I corrected the script, have you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month-year format is a big big NO, and you have to somehow overcome it. For this example I create a MEMORY table `months`, and I use several joins with this table.

```
create table months (month_year_int int, month_year varchar(30)) engine=memory;
insert months 
select 201601 as month_year_int, 'January 2016' as month_year
      union all select 201602, 'February 2016'
      union all select 201603, 'March 2016'
      union all select 201604, 'April 2016'
      union all select 201605, 'May 2016'
      union all select 201606, 'June 2016'
      union all select 201607, 'July 2016'
      union all select 201608, 'August 2016'
      union all select 201609, 'September 2016'
      union all select 201610, 'October 2016'
      union all select 201611, 'November 2016'
      union all select 201612, 'December 2016'
      union all select 201701, 'January 2017'
;
```

All these would have been avoided if you had used a proper model for your data. Anyway, this is a solution whis does not use the My-Sql proprietary variable pattern (a [rextester demo here](http://rextester.com/XFS82137)):

```
select 
    x.month_year, 
    coalesce(t.mv, 0) MV, 
    sum(y.mv) as AMV, 
    coalesce(t.mi, 0) AMV, 
    sum(y.mi) as AMI from 
(
    select 
        m.month_year_int, 
        m.month_year, 
        coalesce(t.mv, 0) as mv, 
        coalesce(t.mi) as mi
    from months m left join test t on m.month_year = t.month_year 
) x 
left join 
(
    select 
        m.month_year_int, 
        m.month_year, 
        coalesce(t.mv, 0) as mv, 
        coalesce(t.mi) as mi
    from months m
        left join test t on m.month_year = t.month_year 
) y on x.month_year_int > y.month_year_int - 1
left join test t on x.month_year = t.month_year
group by x.month_year_int
order by x.month_year_int
;
```

Comment: Seems that last union all select 201701, 'January 2016' should be union all select 201701, 'January 2017'

Comment: Thanks, updating!